# Get last executed time and name for SQL Server users functions

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I need to log SQL Server user-defined functions (Progammability/functions) and stored procedure calls (name of function/SP and last execution time).

For stored procedures, I use extended events (Session -> EVENT sqlserver.sp_statement_completed).

Is it possible to use same approach for functions?

Comment: @MitchWheat I've added method that i'm using now

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this method now:

```
INSERT INTO @Table
    SELECT DISTINCT ct.objectid as ObjectId,
    GETDATE() LastDate

FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) AS ct
INNER JOIN Sysobjects s on s.id = ct.objectid
WHERE s.xtype in ('V', 'IF', 'FN', 'TF') --Views, Table-valued Functions, Scalar-valued functions
```

So, I call this code by timer (for example every hour). It don't show exact call time but allows me to find non-using functions etc.